# How to expand the QCD loops in terms of infrared scale for matching with heavy quark effective field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

According to Manohar:"argument applies almost without change to a practical example,the derivation of the HQET Lagrangian to one-loop."

on page 37 of the following paper on effective field theories:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05863

Question: I want to know what is the IR scale we expand the full theory in terms of it to find the matching sector, or the same IR scale that if one expands it away finds the analytical dependence of the HQET on that scale(Surely the non-Analytical dependence will be dropped via this expansion)?

Comment: The IR scale should be $\Lambda_{QCD}$, but you should focus on the hard scale, which is what matters when it comes to matching. You're looking at a $M/\Lambda_{QCD}$ expansion of QCD, and you take the first order to compare with HQET. In other cases, the soft scale might not be $\Lambda_{QCD}$, it depends on the physical scenario.

Comment: Well, sounds reasonable, but you should invert the fraction I guess.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that.